# How to get python package `awswranger` to accept a custom `endpoint_url`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-data-wrangler

I'm attempting to use the python package `awswrangler` to access a non-AWS S3 service.

The [AWS Data Wranger docs](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/tutorials/002%20-%20Sessions.html) state that you need to create a `boto3.Session()` object.

The problem is that the `boto3.client()` supports setting the `endpoint_url`, but `boto3.Session()` does not [(docs here)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html).

In my previous uses of `boto3` I've always used the `client` for this reason.

Is there a way to create a `boto3.Session()` with a custom `endpoint_url` or otherwise configure `awswrangler` to accept the custom endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the configuration for `awswrangler`:

```
import awswrangler as wr

wr.config.s3_endpoint_url = 'https://custom.endpoint'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Any configuration variables for awswrangler can be overwritten directly using the `wr.config` config object as you stated in your answer, but it may be cleaner or preferable in some use cases to use environment variables](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/021%20-%20Global%20Configurations.html?highlight=config#21---Global-Configurations).

In that case, simply set `WR_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` to your custom endpoint, and the configuration will reflect that when you import the library.

Answer (score 2):

Once you create your session, you can use `client` as well. For example:

```python
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.client('s3', endpoint_url='<custom-endpoint>')
```

Comment: This didn't get the `endpoint_url` to pass through to `awswrangler` when `session` is handed to `awswrangler`.

Comment: @DavidParks I think you should re-phrase your question, that you are asking only about `awswrangler as wr`. I answered to your original question regarding `Is there a way to create a boto3.Session() with a custom endpoint_url?` and the use of its client, not how do I modify `awswrangler` default endpoint.

Comment: I agree, I was ambiguous about that, my fault. The `awswrangler` docs seemed very explicit that I should handle those matters in the session. I will update the wording. I do very much appreciate your answer and help. It got me past what I was stuck on and looking in the right area for the answer.