# boto3 change the endpoint of session

Tags: python, lakefs

I want to use LakeFS configurations for my boto session. I tried using this, but still, it gives me the default one

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 
    endpoint_url=lakefsEndPoint,
    aws_access_key_id=lakefsAccessKey,
    aws_secret_access_key=lakefsSecretKey
)


s3_session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=lakefsAccessKey,
    aws_secret_access_key=lakefsSecretKey
)
```

How can I get the new session? I want to write the data using aws wrangler, that's why I need to get the BOTO session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get python package \`awswranger\` to accept a custom \`endpoint\_url\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791435/how-to-get-python-package-awswranger-to-accept-a-custom-endpoint-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the resource by using the session directly:

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(...)

resource = session.resource('s3', endpoint_url=lakefsEndPoint)
```

However, in awswrangler, you can pass the session directly with the `boto3_session` kwarg and set the `endpoint_url` using the config:

```py
import awswrangler as wr

wr.config.s3_endpoint_url = lakefsEndPoint

df = wr.s3.read_parquet('s3://bucket/key.parquet', boto3_session=session)
```